# Is there a way to let Numpy know that a column is sorted when doing a slice? Presumably it could then slice faster?

Tags: numpy, sorting, slice

For example:

```
arr = np.array([[0,1],[0,2],[0,3],[1,4],[1,5],[2,6],[3,7]])
arr2 = arr[arr[:,0]==1]
```

In this example its very fast as is, but if I am trying to slice something similar but with 100 million rows, would it help if I sorted it on the first column and the somehow told Numpy that its sorted? Ie. once you find the first true value, other true values are adjacent?

Comment: Keep in mind that your expression has several steps.  `arr[:,0]==1` producing a 1d boolean array.  then the `arr[mask]` indexing.  `arr[n:]` slice would be faster (a `view`), but getting the `n` from the equality test (or instead of it) isn't trivial.

Comment: If you were writing your own code in `c` (or maybe `numba`) you can think serially/iteratively, finding the first True condition in an array.  But with the compiled `numpy` methods we generally have to think in parallel/vectorized terms - actions that apply to the whole array without control of the order.  `numpy` methods do iteration in compiled code, but few, if any, have a notion of `first find then break`.  Normally they operate on the **whole** array.

Comment: Ahhh OK I see. So no gains from sorting first because it flattens first and loses the sortedness anyways?